# Kotlin native hello world compilation failed on arch linux. UnsatidfiedLinkError: Undefined symbol: __clock_nanosleep, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: android, linux, kotlin, kotlin-native

I have already compiled this simple example on windows using this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/using-command-line-compiler.html

Then I tried to set up my arch Linux environment, using this
https://snapcraft.io/install/kotlin-native/arch

while also installing the android sdk from AUR using this,
https://noirscape.github.io/guides/2018/06/14/android-sdk-arch-linux.html

ls gives this - build build.gradle.kts main.kt. README.md settings.gradle.kts src 
I am not using gradle for this problem but it is installed

cat main.kt gives this -

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello Kotlin/Native!")
}
```

when I run kotlinc-native main.kt -o build/hello 
I get   error: compilation failed: /var/lib/snapd/snap/kotlin-native/13/konan/nativelib/libllvmstubs.so: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1:undefined symbol: __clock_nanosleep, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

*source files main.kt
*compiler version info: Konan: 0.9.3 / Kotlin: 1.3.0
*Output Kind PROGRAM

exception: java.lang.unsatisfiedLinkError: /var/lib/snapd/snap/kotlin-native/13/konan/nativelib/libllvmstubs.so: /snap/core/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 undefined symbol: __clock_nanosleep, version GLIBC_PRIVATE

then there are a lot of at java.base at llvm.llvm and at org.jetbrains.kotlin after that.  If those are important I can let me know.

I am a baby kotlin user and a baby Linux user.  I believe learning starts from the bottom up so I really want to understand what is happening here instead of just solving it by using gradle or android studios.

I have a feeling that the compiler might not have downloaded all the dependencies on its first run or maybe this has something to do with the symbolic link I made from the first link.  please help me understand

ps. I am also sharing a git repo for this project across the two OS's.  So maybe this is windows getting in the way but I cant really see how that could be.

Comment: Seems like this snapcraft thing is outdated, why don't you download K/N compiler from official GH repository(https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/latest)